# LaTeX query about using LaTeX

Tags: sourcecode

Is it posible to "nest" the LaTeX source code to a text edit program, so it would be easier for users to use it.
  I would like to ask you how could I get the LaTeX source code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please clarify what you mean by nesting LaTeX source code in a text edit program? Relatedly, why did you set the "bold" tag?

Comment: As far as I understand the question, LaTeX and editor are 100% separate. Which is a good thing, if you do not like one editor you can just use another, unlike, say, Word. On the other hand both MikTeX and TeX Live installations nowadays do install a small editor for peoiple to start from.

Comment: why is this question tagged **bold** ? The source of latex is distributed with every tex distribution, but it isn't at all clear what you are asking, what do you want to do with that source?

Comment: Are you asking about code folding? You can start by looking at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/15925

Comment: I think the question might be about hiding the LaTeX code details, so that the user needs only type text. A bit like Lyx maybe.

Comment: I am working under a project and we would like to Implement LaTeX into our text editor to be more user-friendly and I was wondering if that is posible.

Comment: most latex editors provide whatever front end view that they want to provide but to call latex they just call a latex command via a system call they don't try to embed tex within the compiled source of the editor

Comment: I think it's possible to achieve it, but as in the answer says, you should start for understand the code. Also there are many free text editors able to work with LaTeX code, perhaps you could check that code for help you.

Comment: I don't think that including the code for LaTeX in your editor will make it easier to use. I think it will make it harder to use and a lot more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

There are editors which do code folding for LaTeX if I understand your first question, if not, LyX, http://www.lyx.org is probably the best option as Fritz suggested in the comments.

Source code for LaTeX is available from CTAN: [http://www.ctan.org/‎](http://www.ctan.org/%E2%80%8E) but you'll want to start by understanding Documented LaTeX sources (.dtx files): https://texfaq.org/FAQ-dtx

You should probably start w/ the LaTeX Project page: http://www.latex-project.org/

Or here: http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.pdf

For the actual source you want: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e

Comment: I am working under a project and we would like to Implement LaTeX into our text editor to be more user-friendly and I was wondering if that is posible.

Comment: Yes, there are a number of projects which do that sort of thing.

Comment: Are there any suggestion how to implement the code to the text editor?

Comment: @Vasil What do you mean exactly? If this answer doesn't address your question, I think it is because people are not at all clear what you are asking. If you want to do something like LyX, say, you can look at that project. But it isn't clear if that is what you are trying to do at all...

Comment: I aplogise for the confusion. I am trying to create something like LyX - yes. And I was wondering if there is a way to do it.

Comment: Am i able to see the LaTeX source code from somewhere so I can use it to implement it to a new text editor, edit it to be more user-friendly

Comment: https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf

Comment: All I need to do now is to see how to set the code to the text editor.